# How to get the assembly code from IonMonkey

Tags: javascript, memory, assembly, gdb, spidermonkey

for studying purposes I am trying to find out the memory address of a variable after JIT compilation from IonMonkey ( IonMonkey is part of SpiderMonkey, the Javascript engine of Mozilla )

Until now I have followed these instruction https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Hacking_Tips#Printing_the_generated_assembly_code_(from_gdb)

I use GDB and I run the same procedure with 2 different test files.

```
   function f(a, b) { return a + b; }
   var shell = "AAAA";
   for (var  i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){ f( shell[0], shell[1] ); }
```

and this one:

```
function f(a, b) { return a + b; }
var shell = "AAAA";
for (var  i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){ f( shell[1], shell[1] ); }
```

I believed that this way I would spot the difference between the generated code and find out where is the "shell" variable is located.
The problem is that the generated code is exactly the same. I also tried different versions of simple function such as minus or print but the generated code is totally different.

Can anyone suggest any way so I can get the memory address of the variable?

The assembly generated code is

```
  0x7ffff7ff3ac8:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%r10
   0x7ffff7ff3acd:   shr    $0x2f,%r10
   0x7ffff7ff3ad1:   cmp    $0x1fff2,%r10d
   0x7ffff7ff3ad8:   je     0x7ffff7ff3ae3
   0x7ffff7ff3ade:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3b85
   0x7ffff7ff3ae3:   mov    0x28(%rsp),%r10
   0x7ffff7ff3ae8:   shr    $0x2f,%r10
   0x7ffff7ff3aec:   cmp    $0x1fff5,%r10d
   0x7ffff7ff3af3:   je     0x7ffff7ff3afe
   0x7ffff7ff3af9:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3b85
   0x7ffff7ff3afe:   mov    0x30(%rsp),%r10
   0x7ffff7ff3b03:   shr    $0x2f,%r10
   0x7ffff7ff3b07:   cmp    $0x1fff5,%r10d
   0x7ffff7ff3b0e:   je     0x7ffff7ff3b19
   0x7ffff7ff3b14:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3b85
   0x7ffff7ff3b19:   mov    0x28(%rsp),%r8
   0x7ffff7ff3b1e:   movabs $0x7fffffffffff,%rax
   0x7ffff7ff3b28:   and    %r8,%rax
   0x7ffff7ff3b2b:   mov    0x30(%rsp),%r9
   0x7ffff7ff3b30:   movabs $0x7fffffffffff,%rdi
   0x7ffff7ff3b3a:   and    %r9,%rdi
   0x7ffff7ff3b3d:   mov    $0x1670b78,%r11d
   0x7ffff7ff3b43:   mov    (%r11),%rcx
   0x7ffff7ff3b46:   cmp    %rcx,%rsp
   0x7ffff7ff3b49:   jbe    0x7ffff7ff3b8f
   0x7ffff7ff3b4f:   callq  0x7ffff7ff39a0
   0x7ffff7ff3b54:   test   %rbp,%rbp
   0x7ffff7ff3b57:   je     0x7ffff7ff3bd6
   0x7ffff7ff3b5d:   movabs $0xfffa800000000000,%rcx
   0x7ffff7ff3b67:   or     %rbp,%rcx
   0x7ffff7ff3b6a:   retq   
   0x7ffff7ff3b6b:   nop
                     ...
   0x7ffff7ff3b72:   nop
   0x7ffff7ff3b73:   movabs $0xffffffffffffffff,%r11
   0x7ffff7ff3b7d:   push   %r11
   0x7ffff7ff3b7f:   callq  0x7ffff7fe9400
   0x7ffff7ff3b84:   int3   
   0x7ffff7ff3b85:   pushq  $0x0
   0x7ffff7ff3b8a:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3c40
   0x7ffff7ff3b8f:   sub    $0x28,%rsp
   0x7ffff7ff3b93:   mov    %r9,0x20(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3b98:   mov    %r8,0x18(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3b9d:   mov    %rdi,0x10(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3ba2:   mov    %rcx,0x8(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3ba7:   mov    %rax,(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3bab:   pushq  $0x280
   0x7ffff7ff3bb0:   callq  0x7ffff7fee880
   0x7ffff7ff3bb5:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%r9
   0x7ffff7ff3bba:   mov    0x18(%rsp),%r8
   0x7ffff7ff3bbf:   mov    0x10(%rsp),%rdi
   0x7ffff7ff3bc4:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
   0x7ffff7ff3bc9:   mov    (%rsp),%rax
   0x7ffff7ff3bcd:   add    $0x28,%rsp
   0x7ffff7ff3bd1:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3b4f
   0x7ffff7ff3bd6:   sub    $0x40,%rsp
   0x7ffff7ff3bda:   mov    %r9,0x38(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3bdf:   mov    %r8,0x30(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3be4:   mov    %rdi,0x28(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3be9:   mov    %rsi,0x20(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3bee:   mov    %rbx,0x18(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3bf3:   mov    %rdx,0x10(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3bf8:   mov    %rcx,0x8(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3bfd:   mov    %rax,(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff3c01:   push   %rdi
   0x7ffff7ff3c02:   push   %rax
   0x7ffff7ff3c03:   pushq  $0x500
   0x7ffff7ff3c08:   callq  0x7ffff7fec370
   0x7ffff7ff3c0d:   mov    %rax,%rbp
   0x7ffff7ff3c10:   mov    0x38(%rsp),%r9
   0x7ffff7ff3c15:   mov    0x30(%rsp),%r8
   0x7ffff7ff3c1a:   mov    0x28(%rsp),%rdi
   0x7ffff7ff3c1f:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%rsi
   0x7ffff7ff3c24:   mov    0x18(%rsp),%rbx
   0x7ffff7ff3c29:   mov    0x10(%rsp),%rdx
   0x7ffff7ff3c2e:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
   0x7ffff7ff3c33:   mov    (%rsp),%rax
   0x7ffff7ff3c37:   add    $0x40,%rsp
   0x7ffff7ff3c3b:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3b5d
   0x7ffff7ff3c40:   pushq  $0x0
   0x7ffff7ff3c45:   jmpq   0x7ffff7fe9008
   0x7ffff7ff3c4a:   hlt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to build the engine with debugging enabled, then use the `IONFLAGS` env var: per [the spew handling code](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/04d8c309fe72/js/src/ion/IonSpewer.cpp#l216) you can enable spew channels like `codegen`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're only looking at the function `f`, which simply adds its arguments; tracing through the code quickly, I notice that there is only one reverse branch within the function, and there is no flow path that could possibly *loop*.

It looks like this function reads two arguments off the stack, typechecks them (and breaks into the interpreter if the typecheck fails), calls one function on those objects, and returns the result; everything after the "..." is error-handling code. If you want a better test, try shoving the for loop into its own function, and printing the result of adding shell[0] and shell[1].

Alternatively, you're already using GDB... set a breakpoint in the JITed code, and poke at them. Chances are, that breakpoint will be hit 1000000 times, and the arguments will be the same each time.

Finally, you can get the current instruction pointer with a sequence like (x86/gas):

```
call 1n
1: pop %eax
```

This may be easier for your purposes :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not much but I found a way to locate simple integer variables and strings.

1. Run js shell with gdb
2. Place a breakpoint Following the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Hacking_Tips#Printing_the_generated_assembly_code_%28from_gdb%29)
3. do a x/50i $pc-1 and start!

### For integers:

**Javascript code**

```
var sum =10;
for (var  i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++ ) { sum = sum + 1; }
```

**Generated code**

```
   0x7ffff7ff34a7:   movabs $0x7ffff5e4c060,%rax
   0x7ffff7ff34b1:   mov    0x10(%rax),%rax
   0x7ffff7ff34b5:   movabs $0x1670b98,%r11
   0x7ffff7ff34bf:   cmpl   $0x0,(%r11)
   0x7ffff7ff34c3:   jne    0x7ffff7ff3542
   0x7ffff7ff34c9:   mov    0x6c0(%rax),%ecx -- Load var i
   0x7ffff7ff34cf:   cmp    $0x186a0,%ecx    -- compare with 100000
   0x7ffff7ff34d5:   jge    0x7ffff7ff34fe   -- jump greater or equal [loop end]
   0x7ffff7ff34db:   mov    0x6b8(%rax),%edx -- load var sum
   0x7ffff7ff34e1:   add    $0x1,%edx        -- +1 to sum
   0x7ffff7ff34e4:   jo     0x7ffff7ff3561
   0x7ffff7ff34ea:   mov    %edx,0x6b8(%rax) -- store sum
   0x7ffff7ff34f0:   add    $0x1,%ecx        -- +1 to i
   0x7ffff7ff34f3:   mov    %ecx,0x6c0(%rax) -- store i
   0x7ffff7ff34f9:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff34b5   -- continue loop
   0x7ffff7ff34fe:   movabs $0xfff9000000000000,%rcx
   0x7ffff7ff3508:   retq
```

**Now we check the memory**

var i   -- 0x1696230 + 0x6c0 = 0x16968f0
var sum -- 0x1696230 + 0x6b8 = 0x16968e8

```
0x00007ffff7ff34b5 (gdb) info registers rax 0x1696230
(gdb) x/w 0x16968f0:  0x0000044a
(gdb) x/w 0x16968e8:  0x00000454
```

0x0000044a = hex( 44a ) = dec( 1098 )
0x00000454 = hex( 454 ) = dec( 1108 )

So, that's the way we find the memory address of an integer.

### For strings:

**Javascript code**

```
for (var  i = 0; i < 100000; i++){ shell="ABCDEFG" }
```

*info* ascii( "ABCDEFG" ) = hex( 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 )

**Generated code**

```
   0x7ffff7ff341f:   movabs $0x7ffff5e4c060,%rax
   0x7ffff7ff3429:   mov    0x10(%rax),%rax
   0x7ffff7ff342d:   movabs $0x1670b98,%r11
   0x7ffff7ff3437:   cmpl   $0x0,(%r11)       -- compare addr 0
   0x7ffff7ff343b:   jne    0x7ffff7ff34d7    -- jump not equal
   0x7ffff7ff3441:   mov    0x6b8(%rax),%ecx  -- load var i
   0x7ffff7ff3447:   cmp    $0x186a0,%ecx     -- compare i with 100000
   0x7ffff7ff344d:   jge    0x7ffff7ff3493    -- jump greater or equal [loop end]
   0x7ffff7ff3453:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3470    -- continue loop 
   0x7ffff7ff3458:   push   %rdx                                  
   0x7ffff7ff3459:   lea    0x6c0(%rax),%rdx                      
   0x7ffff7ff3460:   callq  0x7ffff7fe9a48                        
   0x7ffff7ff3465:   pop    %rdx                                  
   0x7ffff7ff3466:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff3470                        
   0x7ffff7ff346b:   hlt                                          
   0x7ffff7ff3...:   hlt    -- filled with hlt                                          
   0x7ffff7ff346f:   hlt                                          
   0x7ffff7ff3470:   movabs $0xfffafffff5f3a280,%r11  -- Load address "shell"        
   0x7ffff7ff347a:   mov    %r11,0x6c0(%rax) -- store address to var shell 
   0x7ffff7ff3481:   mov    $0x1,%edx        
   0x7ffff7ff3486:   add    %ecx,%edx        -- +1 to i
   0x7ffff7ff3488:   mov    %edx,0x6b8(%rax) -- store var i
   0x7ffff7ff348e:   jmpq   0x7ffff7ff342d   -- continue loop
   0x7ffff7ff3493:   movabs $0xfff9000000000000,%rcx
   0x7ffff7ff349d:   retq
```

var shell -- 0x1696230 + 0x6c0 = 0x16968f0

```
(gdb) info registers rax    0x1696230:  0xf5f3a280
(gdb) x/w 0x16968f0:    0xf5f3a280

(gdb) x/20w 0x7ffff5f3a280
0x7ffff5f3a280: 0x00000078  0x00000000  0xf5f3a290  0x00007fff
0x7ffff5f3a290: 0x00420041  0x00440043  0x00460045  0x00000047
0x7ffff5f3a2a0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

**0x7ffff5f3a290:   0x00420041  0x00440043  0x00460045  0x00000047**
We got our string!